# Can't read a whole JSON file

Tags: java, json, jackson

As the title says I am not able to deserialize a whole JSON file into an ArrayList, and more specifically, my code reads only the first item from the file and ignores the rest.

Comment: We would need both `MyClass` class code and also the JSON you are trying to deserialize in order to be able to help you.

Comment: What does mapper.readValue() actually do? It sounds like it reads a single value and returns it in an ArrayList. You might need a loop to read all the values and add each one to your arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON file is not valid. You only have a couple of JSON objects, but you need to bundle them together in a JSON Array as follows:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "country": "gr",
    "features": [
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.7123809523809526,
      0.75,
      0.0
    ],
    "timestamp": 1637924593676
  },
  {
    "name": "Scott",
    "country": "gb",
    "features": [
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.6598639455782312,
      0.2,
      0.15601209271073035
    ],
    "timestamp": 1637924610010
  },
  {
    "name": "Michael",
    "country": "it",
    "features": [
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.6877551020408165,
      0.75,
      0.06856164464370273
    ],
    "timestamp": 1638458784201
  }
]
```

---

In order to fix your writing method you need to provide it with a list of `MyClass` objects instead of a single one at a time (you don't need to append while writing with this solution):

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {
        List<MyClass> objectsToSerialize = new ArrayList<>();
        objectsToSerialize.add(new MyClass("Name1", "Country1", new double[] { 1.0 }));
        objectsToSerialize.add(new MyClass("Name2", "Country2", new double[] { 2.0 }));
        objectsToSerialize.add(new MyClass("Name3", "Country3", new double[] { 3.0 }));

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myclass.json")));
        mapper.writeValue(out, objectsToSerialize);
    }
}
```

This means your method must accept a list of `MyClass` and not a single `MyClass`:

```java
private static void writeJSON(List<MyClass> objectsToSerialize) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myclass.json")));
    mapper.writeValue(out, objectsToSerialize);
}
```

---

If you need to continuously add content to your JSON file you could do as follows:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {
        // Read the file
        List<MyClass> myClasses = readFromFile();
        
        // Add whatever MyClass objects you want to the read List
        myClasses.add(new MyClass("Name1", "Country1", new double[] { 1.0 }));
        myClasses.add(new MyClass("Name2", "Country2", new double[] { 2.0 }));
        myClasses.add(new MyClass("Name3", "Country3", new double[] { 3.0 }));
        
        // Write the whole List again
        writeJSON(myClasses);
    }

    private static List<MyClass> readFromFile() throws IOException {
        String jsonString = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("myclass.json"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>() {});
    }

    private static void writeJSON(List<MyClass> objectsToSerialize) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myclass.json")));
        mapper.writeValue(out, objectsToSerialize);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check it ;)

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my initial post, please check it!

Comment: As I wrote, you need to serialize the list at once and not one `MyClass` at a time. Just do it as my answer suggests.

Comment: Thank you, it works, but the thing is (maybe I didn't mention that) that I want to load my myClassArray with the JSON file's components whenever the program restarts. So, the objects that I add at the second or the third time I run the program, will not get recognized (for the reason I mentioned  in my update text). Do you have any ideas on that?

Comment: Then that is not going to work. Either you do some black magic to rewrite the already written file (which I totally do not recommend) or you write the full content again, instead of appending whatever was added. The logic would be you read the file into a `List<MyClass>`, you add whatever `MyClass` objects to the list and you persist the whole list again and overwrite the file. I will add this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your json file does not contain valid json array.
It should looks like:

```
[ 
 { ... },
 { ... }
]
```

Not

```
{ ... }
{ ... }
```

I think you wrote json as single objects, not as array.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that the mapper you are using is Jackson's `Object Mapper`. In your line of code:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> myClassArray = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<ArrayList<MyClass>>() {});
```

there is no real error. Rather, the method with which you corrected your prior error is flawed:

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
```

You are just bypassing the initial error, the problem is that your JSON is incorrectly formatted, and so it cannot be casted into a Collection. Check your original file, or put the string into an online JSON formatter to verify it is valid. Here is a potential link: https://jsonlint.com/.